# Timeseries forecast for multiple variables using loop?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I want to coduct a forecast analysis on my dataset. Some insights into the dataset:

- I have 10 Products each having a specific Id Number. These numbers are random and dont have any pattern.
- Each product has data starting from the year 2016 till 2018 for each month. So, 36 Observation Points for each product.
- All These products are present in a single dataset in the column Format and a total of 300 rows (certain products have missing data):

  Column names: Prod_Id  Year  Month  Sales_data

Would appreciate a guidance on the optimal approach that can be taken?

I am thinking of the following:

- Create a new vector with the unique Product_Ids and use its length to create a loop
- Perform the forecast Analysis for one of the products and contain it in a Loop for other variables.

I am absolutely new to R and would appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: Totally get the desire for help, but Stack Overflow is meant for coding help, not for completely getting started on something new (I think there are other overflow sites for this kind of help).  Try taking a crack at it, posting your data in a reproducible format and showing us what you've done.  Here's a good place to get started with for loops and R in general: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html.  Read the whole book--it's amazing for using R for data science.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the links, i am looking for help with respect to approach. Could you suggest a source where i may ask this? Stackexchange or Crossvalidated?